# why is my css not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created a react component and imported my external css file. some of the css is working correctly but the majority of it isnt being displayed. not sure what im doing incorrectly.if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appriciated.

this is my CSS

```
.Layout{
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 100px 1px rgba(82, 82, 82, 1);
    height: 3em;
    width: 100vw;
};
.Logo{
    flex: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20;
    padding-left: 15px;
};
.Search{
    flex: 5;
};
.Input{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20;
    width: 400;
    border-radius: 8
}
```

this is my react component

```
 import React, { Component }     from 'react';
    import { connect }              from 'react-redux';
    import { Locate, autoLocate }   from '../Actions'
    import '../CSS/Header.css'

    class Header extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={ };
            this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
        }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.autoWeather('autoip');
    }

    onSearchChange(event){
        this.props.fetchTodayWeather(event.target.value);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="Layout">
                    <div className="Logo">Weather Now</div>
                    <div className="Search"><input className="Input" placeholder='search the weather in your area' value={ this.props.query } onChange={ this.onSearchChange } /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const query = state.locate.query;

        return{ query };
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return{
            autoWeather:(location) => dispatch(autoLocate(location)),
            fetchTodayWeather: (location) => dispatch(Locate(location))

    };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header)
```

Comment: try to put both files is the same directory to locate the problem.

Comment: You have semicolons after your closing curly braces in your CSS. This is invalid in CSS (you're likely getting this from writing JS). Remove them and see what happens

Comment: missing semicolon? import { Locate, autoLocate }   from '../Actions';

Comment: This is why one always runs their CSS (and HTML) through the validator.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a problem loading CSS file. I face the same problem and I able solve it using two ways.

1. In your `webpack.config.js` file, does it contains CSS loader like
   below

   ```
   {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
   },
   ```

   And for more details about CSS loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader
2. And also you can add external CSS file into index.html too. Like
   below

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />`